# Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted:

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon

I am working on a project with Katalon Studio 7.7.2. The automation test does not work as desired.
I tried it on 2 different ways. I have run it with chrome normally an with chrome (headless). Both unsuccessful.

That's the error:

```js
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <button _ngcontent-xar-c91="" type="submit" triggers="click:blur" class="cc-tr-btn ng-star-inserted">...</button> is not clickable at point (388, 593). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-xar-c51="" class="row align-items-center">...</div>
```

At the point where the error occurs is a button that redirects to another page. On the same page are two drop-down lists that cannot be selected by the Test Automation Katalon. When the error occurs, the test automation stops and the two dropdown lists remain unselected. Item 19 (see picture) is also a drop-down menu - but this works. Item 31 is or should already be the next page.

[image: 1]

I need an excatly descrption where I must push the Element/Code. I have tried different solutions.
But I don't now wehre I must exactly push the Element like new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), ..  and so on.
It would be good to get some screenshots.

I used the possibility to go to the following Itternet page for the research: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/troubleshoot-common-execution-exceptions-web-test.html
But there I have also only Elements or code and not a exactly description where I must push the instructions.

Thank you for your help!